# Boolean difference removes unintended parts of a mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I joined several meshes into one using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.  
When I assign a Boolean modifier with difference operation to my mesh - some parts of it just disappear.
I've already checked double vertices and inverted normals.
 What could be wrong with that? 
Thanks!

[Blend file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CC24p4amEjgc9YErCXiOMcqV6Zuh_VlX/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Before bool diff]

[image: After bool diff]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of boolean algorithm gets buggy when you are trying to apply Difference operation to meshes that basicly consists of 2 or more joined meshes.
You can pass through it following next stepps:

1. Select crystal mesh and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to enter Edit Mode
2. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything
3. <kbd>P</kbd> *> Separate > By Loose Parts* to break it down into separate meshes
4. Repeat Boolean Difference operation with desired meshes and apply boolean modifiers by hovering mouse cursor over modifier and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
5. Select all desired meshes and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd> to join them back
6. If you want to keep Boolean procedural, left modified meshes separately and join rest of them

Comment: Thanks. Good to know that I thought the same. I was going to cut out some creases is separate objects and then join them as a mesh. But I thought maybe it was possible to do it as I described in question for more productivity 